# Consulta do banco para outra variável

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho o seguinte cenário, eu realizo uma consulta ao banco e retorno todos os dados:

```
<?php
include ("conectar.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM pontos ORDER by pontos DESC LIMIT 0,10";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    $lista = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

        $lista++;
?>
```

Então eu preciso imprimir uma tabela com o numero academico e os pontos,

```
        <td align="center"><?php echo $row[0];?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $row[1];?></td>
```

Até aí ok, a questão é que eu precisava pegar os valores da

```
$row[0]
```

E passar para outra variavel, que será utilizada para consultar um webservice.

```
$user1->value = 'row[0]';
```

Só consigo passar um valor vindo de um input, e eu precisava que os valores viessem diretamente da primeira coluna do banco, alguém tem idéia de como fazer isso?

```
$user2->value = $_POST["username"];
```

Comment: Está variável que você precisa carregar, está em outro arquivo php?

Comment: @LuisHenrique no mesmo arquivo.

Comment: O que tem no `var_dump()` do `$row[0]`?

Comment: Por que não pode fazer `$user1->value = $row[0];`?

Comment: @LuisHenrique, me perdoa por ser leigo na linguagem, eu fiz a mesma coisa mas tinha colocado entre aspas, agora sem deu certo, muito grato.

Comment: Sem problemas. Coloquei uma resposta com isso, achei que houvesse algum motivo para não atribuir direto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta atribuir o valor diretamente a variável desejada durando o loop.

```
<?php
include ("conectar.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM pontos ORDER by pontos DESC LIMIT 0,10";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    $lista = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $user1->value = $row[0];
        $lista++;
?>
```